# Decrypt data in web app only if device unlock solved (biometrics, PIN)

Tags: authentication, encryption, web-applications, progressive-web-apps, biometrics

In a web app I can encrypt data via web crypto:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt

I can store the key as non-extractable CryptoKey in indexed db.

Since the device owner might not operate the device, how can I trigger device unlock before decryption and check whether the owner wants to see the sensitive data or someone else?

In a native app, you have biometrics API on Apple, Google, Microsoft platforms.

Is it possible in a web app?

I took a look at webauthn but it needs to create a credential first.

I already have a credential system, the device is logged in. I would just check biometrics via browser (it is a native app and has access to biometrics API) like a native app could do. Since device can be stolen or just "hijacked" for some seconds or minutes, especially if it does not lock fast automatically.

I just want to prevent seeing or doing sensitive data / things by having access to device biometrics.

Comment: `I already have a credential system, the device is logged in. I would just check biometrics via browser (it is a native app and has access to biometrics API) like a native app could do`
seems you already found a way. Yes, you have to install/register an authentication method. So where's the problem?

Comment: the browsers can check biometrics but I do not write the code for Safari, Chrome, Firefox etc... there is no web API you can make the browser check biometrics and give you yes/no answer (promise)... I know that the device is a logged in device, I do not need full authentication, just make sure the owner uses the device when doing sensitive things... webauthn is a special complex solution that pulls a private key from a pass manager, signs if biometrics ok... it requires a pass manager and I should not force my users to store their secrets in a pass manager...

Comment: I just want the biometrics part and couple decryption to it, not another authentication system... the device is already authenticated and logged in with another logic, I want to couple biometrics as a second step not to some different authentication but for the device to be able to do sensitive things only if the owner operates it (like my native banking app does a biometrics check before it decrypts my card data and shows it, even if I am logged in) I would like the same capability from a web app